# Gulp less and then minify task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have to make 2 steps in gulp:

1. Make a .css file form less
2. Minify generated css files

This is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require("gulp-watch"),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('watch-less', function () {
    watch({glob: './*.less'}, function (files) { // watch any changes on coffee files
        gulp.start('compile-less'); // run the compile task
    });

    watch({
        glob: ['./*.css', '!./*.min.css']
    }, function(files) {
        gulp.start('minify-css'); // run the compile task
    });
});

gulp.task('compile-less', function () {
    gulp.src('./*.less') // path to your file
    .pipe(less().on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
    gulp.src([
        './*.css',
        '!./*.min.css'
    ])
    .pipe(cssmin().on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
})

gulp.task('default', ['watch-less']);
```

When i start it only first step is done.
Help me please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no needing after time, convinient solution for me was:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./styles/*.less', ['less']);
});

gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src('./styles/*.less')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./styles/'))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./styles'))

});

gulp.task('default', ['less', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 20):

You should keep in mind that with `gulp` you could simply chain operations on a `glob` pattern.

Don't really sure why you need `gulp.watch` when you can use the built-in watcher, this plugin is useful on tricky situations and that's don't seems be the case here, but you can stick with it if you really want to.

Don't forget to `return` your stream so `gulp` knows when a task is finished.

I also generally wrap all my `watchers` inside one `watch task`, not need to separate them.

To me, your gulpfile should look like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
  cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./*.less', ['less']);
});

gulp.task('less', function () {

  return gulp.src('./*.less')
    .pipe(less().on('error', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }))
    .pipe(cssmin().on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

});

gulp.task('default', ['less', 'watch']);
```

Comment: I use gulp.watch to detect new created file when gulp has already started.

Comment: Okay you can stick with it anyway it's not the main content of my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Best of both worlds might be to add the gulp.watch to the default gulp.task and if you require browser-sync it will reload when you make any changes to the folders being watched as shown below:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  less = require('gulp-less'),
  cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  browser = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('less', function() {
  return gulp.src('./*.less')
    .pipe(less().on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }))
    .pipe(cssmin().on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('server', function() {
  browser({
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['less', 'server'], function() {
  gulp.watch('./*.less', ['less', browser.reload]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it with sass. Kind of the same with less.

The difference with the previous answers is that I wanted one more step:

1. Get the sass
2. Transform it into a css and create the file
3. Get that file and minify it.

So the structure would be like this:

```
test.scss
  test.css
    test.min.css
```

```js
var gulp = require("gulp"),    
  sass = require("gulp-sass"),
  rename = require("gulp-rename");


var paths = {
  webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};

paths.scss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.scss";

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src(paths.scss)
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + "css"))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + "css"));
});
```

Added a new answer in case someone want the same thing as me.